# md5sum progress when piped

Tags: pipe, signals, hashsum

I'm comparing two USB devices post-`rsync` with `md5sum /usb1/* /usb2/* | sort` such that all the files, which are at the root of the drives, have their md5 sums calculated, then the output is sorted by md5sum. The entire command expands to `md5sum /usb1/bigfile1 /usb1/bigfile2 /usb2/bigfile1 /usb2/bigfile2`, for example. My impatience has me wondering what the progress is, i.e. which file is it working on right now? Because it's piped into another command, I have no stdout or stderr to see which file it's hashing atm. Is there some sort of command to report on what another command is doing *right now*?

I have this tagged with "signals", but I don't know much about signals to be comfortable interrupting the md5sum process with one. I recall it was possible to send a signal to `dd` to make it report progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) for this:

```
progress -p $(pgrep md5sum)
```

or, if you want to continuously monitor `md5sum`:

```
progress -m -p $(pgrep md5sum)
```

Without using an external tool, you can see what files `md5sum` is currently accessing on Linux by listing `/proc/$(pgrep md5sum)/fd`, and find out more information about the file descriptors (including their position, which shows how much `md5sum` has processed) by looking at the files in `/proc/$(pgrep md5sum)/fdinfo`.

As you mention, `dd` will print out a progress report when it receives `SIGUSR1`, but that’s a feature implemented by `dd` and not a general signal-mediated feature. By default sending `SIGUSR1` to a process will kill it.

Comment: There is also the `pv` command, used like `pv filename | md5sum`

Comment: @EkriirkE there is indeed, but in the context of this question I think `progress` is more appropriate since it allows the OP to track progress on a command that’s already running.

Answer (score 0):

Another command that works like `cat` is `pv`. It pumps the file content into stdout which you pipe into another program (md5sum) and the progress indication is output through stderr.  Though it's only really good for 1 file at a time.  Use like `pv /usb1/bigfile1 | md5sum`